# Validation during post mapping doesn't call ConstraintValidator's isValid function

Tags: java, spring, validation, kotlin, multipartform-data

I have implemented post mapping in one of controller's:

```
@PostMapping("/management/upload/")
fun uploadMultipartFile(@FileNotEmpty @RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile,
                        @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") model: FileUploadForm): ModelAndView {
    print("POST::RECEIVED")
    return ModelAndView("management/upload", "form", FileUploadForm())
}
```

Unfortunately, the request is received without calling `isValid()` function, which I have implemented in the validator below. I've tried many permutations of (`@FileNotEmpty, @RequestParam(...), @Valid`), but neither worked. I have no idea why this validation isn't being called, while it's marked by this annotation.

Here is the form class:

```
data class FileUploadForm(
    @FileNotEmpty
    val file: MultipartFile? = null
)
```

Validation annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = [FileNotEmptyValidatorForMultipartFile::class])
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD,
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
        AnnotationTarget.FILE,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY,
        AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)

annotation class FileNotEmpty (
        val message: String = "{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}",
        val groups: Array<KClass<out Any>> = [],
        val payload: Array<KClass<out Any>> = []
)
```

Finally, the validator:

```
class FileNotEmptyValidatorForMultipartFile : ConstraintValidator<FileNotEmpty, MultipartFile> {

    override fun isValid(value: MultipartFile?, context: ConstraintValidatorContext?): Boolean {
        if (value == null) {
            return false
        }
        return !value.isEmpty || value.name.isNotEmpty()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

`@RequestParam("file")` provides me proper value, but at the same time `file` property in my form model is null. Since I use thymeleaf to create forms and annotations for validation, I need to have proper `file` value inside my model object.

Comment: Valiation annotations, apart from the `@Validated` or `@Valid` require additional configuration (as those are validated by an interceptor and NOT Spring MVC). Instead make your multipart file a part of your `FileUploadForm` and annotate the field with the annotation to have it validated.

Comment: @M.Deinum `MultipartFile` is part of the FileUploadForm already, and it's annotated to be validated in the HTML form

Comment: Do you have a validation implementation on your classpath? Or only the api

Comment: Implementation is attached above (`FileNotEmptyValidatorForMultipartFile`)

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking. Do you have an implementation of the validator api on your classpath like `hibernate-validator` else nothing is going to happen.

Comment: Oh, judging by the fact that I don't really know what you're asking, I don't have one. I will come back to you as soon as I know what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I have and implementation. `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')`

Comment: Have you disabled (maybe by accident) auto configuration? By adding an `@EnableWebMvc` or a custom validator in your configuration? I would suggest to remove the method argument for `MultipartFile` and only leave the form object (and maybe try again).

Comment: Leaving only form object gives no improvement.

Comment: I have made an edit which I hope clarifies something.

Comment: `val`  is final and cannot be reassigned, so it will **always** be `null` in your model. Use `var` instead.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed it. Thanks a lot!